# Multi-records Reading APDU command structure?

Tags: javacard

I have a card support T0 protocol with an applet is installed on it. The host send a "multi-records reading" command to get records data. Records are read which are specified by record identifiers in this data field of this command. These are steps that I did:

1. Select DF
2. Send a command to read sequence of records

   > 00 B2 00 06 16 73 0A 51 02 40 01 54 04 00 10 00 04 73 08 51 02 40 02 54 02 00 01 00

The meaning of the command is as bellow:

- INS = 'B2': read record(s)
- P1 = '00': references the current record (ISO 7814-4, 7.3.3, table 48)
- P2 = '07' = '00000 110' : 
  '0000' indicate current short EF id (ISO   7814-4, 7.3.2, table 47)
  '111'  mean read all records from the last up to P1 (ISO 7814-4, 7.3.3, table 49)
- Le = 16 : data length
- Data field follow the BER-TLV, for example:

> 73 0A 51 02 40 01 54 04 00 10 00 04 
>   Tag'73' indicate that sequence of bytes above consist hierarchy data object structure in data filed (length = '0A') 
>  
>   Tag'51' reference to 2-byte EF identifier = '40 01' 
>   Tag'54' reference to one or more record identifiers, in this case are '00 10' and '00 04'

- Le = '00'
  This is expect respond from card:

> 53 |length of data| record data| 53| length of data| record data|......

I test this command with the card, the card return 'Unknown Error' message.
Could you tell me what is wrong with the command? Am I misunderstood at any points? 
Thanks.

Comment: ISO7816-4 is just a suggestion of what a card might implement. You rather check the documentation of this specific smartcard.

Comment: Are you communicating with the applet from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34079805/5128464)? If so (and the code is the same as in this post), you probably need to use the `setIncomingAndReceive()` (again) in the applet as you are actually sending some data in the command APDU (presumably making it ISO case 4 command) and the card OS needs to know that...otherwise please do clarify the question

Comment: This applet is not the same as previous applet. It shall be return records data when it receive multi-records reading command. Records are specify by record identifiers which are contain in data field of command as I explain above. I also use `setIncomingAndReceive()` method. So the question is what is correct multi-records reading command ? Could you make clear this point for me ?

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. I have never met a card supporting this particular `READ RECORD(S)` variant, but while looking into the 7816-4 I noticed following: tag '54' is used for offset (even when used inside the '73' tag)...you are using it for referencing the records -- which might be a bad idea. Additionally, your example resembles more the INS='B3' variant and not the INS='B2' you are using (Table 48 even states, that the INS='B2' variant does not have any Data field in the command APDU). I wonder whether someone more knowledgeable expresses to it...Can't you just use something simpler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer. My problem is solved 
Actually the return SW = `61 XY` is not error message. According to ISO 7814-3 it mean:

> Process completed normally (SW2 encodes N x , i.e., the number of extra data bytes still available). In cases 1 and 3, the 
>   card should not use such a value. In cases 2 and 4, for transferring response data bytes, the card shall be ready to receive 
>   a GET RESPONSE command with P3 set to the minimum of N x  and N e .

So just need to send a GET RESPONSE command to get response data:

```
00 C0 00 00 XY
```

XY: the number of extra data bytes still available

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be answered without knowing the actual implementation. `6F00` - the status word indicating an unknown error - should only be returned when the implementation has an internal error. For Java Card implementations - for instance - the `6F00` is returned for uncaught exceptions in the `process` method handling the APDU's.

But just like the rest of ISO/IEC 7816-4, nothing is set in stone. It's not even defined when a specific error should be returned, so even the above is unsure. ISO/IEC 7816-4 is thoroughly useless in that regard.